# Symbol not found in debugger only, when having templated template argument

Tags: c++, templates, llvm, lldb, llvm-clang

Given the following code as test.cpp, 
Building using `clang++ -c test.cpp -o test.o -g; clang++ test.o -g -all_load`, setting breakpoint at `return a.getValue();` and attempting to `p a.getValue()` from lldb:

Running llvm 3.8.0 on unix - works perfectly

Running xcode or llvm 8.1.0 on OSX - I get the following error:

```
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __ZNK4Test7MyClassILi2ELi3EE8getValueEv
```

Two interesting facts:

1. If I remove the last template argument - all works well
2. If I build directly without going through the .o file (`clang++ test.cpp`) = all goes well

Anyone has a clue what is going on, and how can it be fixed?

```
namespace Test{
    template<class T>
    class BLA{
    public:
        T getBlaValue() const{return 3;}
    };

    template  <int N1, int N2, template<class T>class Impl = BLA>
    class MyClass {
    private:

    public:

        __attribute__((used))
        int getValue() const
        {
            return 3;
        }
    };

}

int main()
{
    Test::MyClass<2, 3> a;

    return a.getValue();
}
```

Comment: The symbol lldb says it can't find is the method you are trying to call.  So lldb's looking for the right thing.  If the compiler can inline a call everywhere, it doesn't need to produce the function and sometimes doesn't.  You can use nm on the binary and the .o file to confirm that this symbol is missing.  clang really shouldn't elide used functions like this at -O0. When I tried your example with clang-802.0.42 the symbol is present, and I can call it so this might be a new bug?  Make sure you are building at -O0.  If you still see this problem, please file a bug with https://bugs.llvm.org.

Comment: @JimIngham - I've tried clang-802.0.42 and get the same issue (although the error is more descriptive there...). Are you sure that you ran compilation and then linkage? ( 'clang++ -c' and then 'clang++') Also, the function is present in the result, but with slightly different signature (__ZNK4Test7MyClassILi2ELi3E***NS_3BLAE***E8getValueEv)

Comment: That's interesting.  Please file a bug about this.  The difference not primarily the compile vrs. compile -> .o file with separate link, but is whether you have a dSYM or not.  If you compile directly to an executable, clang makes a dSYM automatically, but you can make one after the fact with dsymutil.  Anyway, without the dSYM, it looks like lldb gets the template type wrong (missing the defaulted parameter) and so looks up the wrong symbol. With the dSYM it looks up the name correctly.  It wasn't immediately obvious to me why this happens, however.

Comment: That last parameter is given a DWARF tag (TAG_GNU_template_template_param) that lldb doesn't currently support.  That's why we're getting the name wrong.  I bet going through the dSYM bypasses the name lookup (in ,o file debugging the debugger has to link the DWARF in the .o files into the final image by hand, but it doesn't need to do that for dSYM's.)  So the workaround for now is to make a dSYM and use that for debugging.

Comment: @JimIngham - WOW dSYM did solve the issue, thanks for the detailed analysis! If this is an unsupported tag, should I still file a bug?

Comment: Please do file a bug.  This is not a tag that the DWARF committee has standardized (thus the GNU element of the name) but it is a tag that clang is emitting, so lldb has to deal with it.